# Unable to connect to wifi router: Something wrong with configuration?

Tags: cyanogenmod, wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat

I needed some way to interact between my desktop and my android phone (Cynaogen). I got a router from my friend. To be clear, its not about getting access to internet, I just want to establish LAN connection between by desktop and Android phone.

By logging into the router, I've configured "Wireless Network" to following settings (advanced view).

Problem is even though `XYZ` wifi network is shown in  available networks in Android phone, after entering the password, status is turning to `Saved` and after  a while it says `Authentication Problem`.  I tried rebooting the router, forgetting the network and try connecting again in my phone. I tried connecting using my friend's phone (kitkat 4.4) too. But still it isn't connecting.

```
To make sure MyDslModem does not transmit on illegal frequencies, you must set where you are in the world.


Global Setting   
    Select Profile:     802.11B/G
    Wireless Network:   Enable   
    Select Country:     USA
    You may either choose a channel yourself, or allow to automatically select the best channel.     
    Channel Selection:  Auto
    Select Channel: 1
    Network Name (SSID): XYZ
    Hide SSID:  No   
    Fragmentation Threshold : 2346
    RTS Threshold : 2347
    NitroXM PiggyBack:  Enable   
    WMM:    Disable      

Security Settings    
    Select Security Option:  Wi-Fi Protected Access2
    [disabled] WEP Authentication Mode:     Open     
    [disabled] Select Tx Key Index:     0
    [disabled] Select Key Method:   Pass Phrase
    [disabled] Key:          
    [disabled] WEP Pass Phrase:          
    Select Encryption Protocol: AES-CCMP protocol
    Select Authentication Method:   PSK (Pre Shared Key)
    WPA Pass Phrase:    mypassword@47    
    802.1x Identity String: BSNL Voip gateway        
    [disabled] 802.1x Rekey Timeout: 600         
    [disabled] PMK Caching:     Enabled
```

Comment: It looks like a modem config issue related to wifi encryption setting. Do you have access to web interface for this modem?

Comment: Try to switch different encryption modes